# ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package #Python #Pycharm #pyOCD

Tags: python

When I try to debug pyOCD in Pycharm I get this message. Can somebody tell me what is the problem?

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.2.4\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1415, in _exec
pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals) # execute the script
File "C:/Users/Software/Downloads/pyOCD-master/pyocd/main.py", line 30, in
from . import version
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
```